# Informix dbexport fails with error -425 Database is currently opened by another user?

Tags: informix

I want export an Informix database in order to import later to another instance. To do that I executed the below command and it ended up with error. I restarted the instance but error is still same.

```
bash-2.00$ dbexport mydb1 -ss
-425 - Database is currently opened by another user.
-107 - ISAM error: record is locked.
```

Note that I changed the database mode to online to quiescent mode and Administrator mode (single user mode) also. But same error.

Comment: If you have just restarted the system in single user mode, you shouldn't normally be getting that error. It is odd. There's a long-standing feature request to allow DB-Export to work with a database 'not in exclusive mode'. There are problems with that — the export might be inconsistent. A solution might be to allow several non-exclusive modes: (1) non-exclusive mode locking tables in shared mode before exporting any table; (2) non-exclusive mode locking tables in shared mode before exporting each table (as yet unexported tables might change while the export is in progress). _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ (3) non-exclusive mode retrying at the end of the export if a table is locked on the first attempt to export.  There are probably others.  The current exclusive mode ensures the database doesn't change while the export is in progress.  This means there won't be integrity problems when the data is imported.  Relaxing that may mean that the export is not importable — or that DB-Import must handle/accept problems (reject files, etc).  It is under consideration; it has not been implemented yet.  (And it isn't clear how much of an overkill all of this is.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instractuions:
run onstat -g ses 0 > session.out
Edit session.out and search for that table name. Identify that sesid(session ID) for each query or transaction running on that table. Note: There could be multiple entries on this table.
run onmode -z  to kill each session and release the resources
If onmode -z does not kill hte session(s), the database server will need to be recycled to free up these resources.